# How do I set the Instance Name for instances running SSM Agent?

Tags: raspberry-pi, aws-ssm

I have a machine instance running SSM agent but the Instance Name appear blank within the Managed instances section on the AWS Console. Is there any way I can set the Instance Name at the point of registration, with a flag, or possibly some other way? This is on PI OS Lite.

Comment: To set name of ec2, refer [this](https://serverfault.com/a/963603) thread.

Comment: Thanks amitd, but this is for a managed instance that's only running the SSM agent. It's not an ec2 instance.